# track get post request of android app from eclipse

Tags: android

I am working on android app. i am newbiee i have problem in post requst so i want to track these ajax request can any body tell me how i can get from eclipse what parameter send to which url and what response return from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Log.v("tag","url:" + url);
```

And

```
Log.v("tag","response"+ response);
```

And  then go to logcat window.. find the button that adds filter.. add a filter with any name and tag value "tag" so u can observe only the requested data..

To find logcat, press alt+shift+q.. release then q.. a popup will appear with search field.. swarch for logcat..

Comment: that will work even if we are not testing with apps if i don't have source code?

Comment: There is kind of flag for enabeling or disabling it, but yes it works and when you plug your phone you can see others logs if they exist